# Makefile Gives Missing Parenthesis Stopped Error

Tags: makefile

[Missing Brace Stopped Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLWi.png)

Missing Brace Stopped Error What Should I Do What is the Solution?

Code:

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32
 ASPARAMS = --32
 LDPARAMS = -melf_i386
 
 objects = loader.o kernel.o
 
%.o: %.cpp
g++ $(GPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<
        
%.o: %.s
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<
        
mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)        
        ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)
        
install: mykernel.bin 
        sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

Comment: Please don't link to images on remote sites, as they go away then your question is not readable by others in the future.  And please don't post images to non-graphical questions into StackOverflow, since they can't be searched, copied, etc. and may not be readable to colorblind etc. readers.  Instead cut and paste the text of the message, with formatting, into your question.  Also to get the widest audience it's good to use the C locale for messages (`LC_ALL=C make ...`) or at least translate the message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation of the error is incorrect.  It should be "missing separator", not "missing parenthesis/brace".

The problem is that there is no tab ("separator") before `g++ $(GPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<`

As @MadScientist says, make sure your error messages are in English, quote everything here, and use the "official" translation, don't try to translate by hand, because that may be misleading.

To answer your question, I went and checked the official English translation of your Turkish error, that's how I knew what the real problem was.